# Issues adding a third Join in Access query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to run a SELECT query with references to multiple separate tables, but I'm getting a problem when I try to add more than one connection. As soon as I try to, it tells me that there's a syntax error (missing operator) in the string "P.Category = tblCategoryCodes.ID LEFT JOIN tblSize ON P.Size = tblSize.ID":

```
SELECT 
P.SKU,
P.ProductType,
tblCategoryCodes.Category,
tblSize.Size /*Adding this line breaks it*/
FROM tblProducts AS P
INNER JOIN tblCategoryCodes ON P.Category = tblCategoryCodes.ID 
LEFT JOIN tblSize ON P.Size = tblSize.ID; /*Adding this line breaks it*/
```

I want to add a couple of extra references to other tables and I'm hoping it will be easy enough once I work this out.

Side note: Can't seem to give the Joined tables aliases. That's probably a separate question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS Access requires a particular syntax for multiple joins, involving parentheses that are unnecessary in any other database:

```
SELECT P.SKU, P.ProductType, cc.Category, s.Size 
FROM (tblProducts AS P INNER JOIN
      tblCategoryCodes as cc
      ON P.Category = cc.ID 
     ) LEFT JOIN
     tblSize as s
     ON P.Size = s.ID;
```

I encourage you to use reasonable table aliases for all your tables, so queries are easier to write and to read.

Comment: Ok, so that solves the first one, but where do I find the parenthesis syntax for future things? I'm going to want to add at least one more table to this query and I'm not sure how to extrapolate from that; Is it different for innerVouter joins... etc.

Comment: Ok, so worked out that you just use parentheses to treat the table and what you just joined it to as a single entity, and then join the next one to that (lots of nesting) apparently regardless of the kind of join, but this answer would still benefit from a reference to where this Access syntax is officially documented.

Comment: @IsaacReefman . . . The parentheses are documented (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/inner-join-operation-b9e73ab6-884a-403e-9f22-cb502feae36a).  However, the documentation also supports multiple `on` clauses for a single `join` -- something that is not only unique to MS Access, but that I've happily never seen in practice either.